# Make a column display only when data is in it

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time, formula

I am trying to make a column display only when data is entered in it.  If it has no data, then the column should not display on the page.  I tried this formula, but it isn't working. I will appreciate any opinions on how to fix it. Thanks.

I want the due date to display with "Due" in front of it, only when the event has a due date.

```
=IF([Due Date]=DATE([Year],[Month],[Day])), "Due" AND([Due Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula in calculated column,

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATE([Year],[Month],[Date])),"","Due " & TEXT(DATE([Year],[Month],[Date]),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Year, Month and Date are assumed as columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new column based on Due Date column, create a calculate column in your list and use below formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Due Date]),"","Due "&TEXT([Due Date],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

If you want to show "Due" word in same Due Date column without creating a new calculate column (duplicate information), you can use [JSON column formatting in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) for this.

You have to use JSON like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(Number([$DueDate]) == 0, '', 'Due ' + toLocaleDateString([$DueDate]))"
}
```

Here I am using `Number()` operator to check if date column is empty or not. You can find other ways to check if date column is blank using JSON formatting at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

Where `[$DueDate]` is the internal name of your date column in format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. You can get the exact internal name of your date column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]